# Prove that $\left|\left\{ 1\leq x\leq p^{2}\ :\ p^{2}\mid\left(x^{p-1}-1\right)\right\} \right|=p-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number and to simplify things lets denote
$$
A=\left\{ 1\leq x\leq p^{2}\ :\ p^{2}\mid\left(x^{p-1}-1\right)\right\}
$$
and we have to show that $\left|A\right|=p-1$.

For every $x\in A$ we know that $p^{2}\mid\left(x^{p-1}-1\right)$
which means $x^{p-1}-1=kp$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and as this is
a polynomial of degree $p-1$ it has at most $p-1$ solutions. Therefore $\left|A\right|\leq p-1$.

How can we show there are exactly $p-1$ solutions in $A$?

Comment: Have you covered the fact that the multiplicative group $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$? Probably not (because the question would then be formulated differently), but I'm checking because some answerers may want to use that result :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen We have covered cyclic groups and I know  $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$

Comment: In a cyclic group of order $n$ the equation $x^d=1$ has exactly $\gcd(n,d)$ solutions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Where can i see a proof of that?

Comment: I would expect texts covering cyclic groups to cover that also. Sketch: without loss of generality we can assume that the group is the additive group $\Bbb{Z}_n$. A coset $\overline{a}$ satisfies $d\overline{a}=\overline{0}$ if and only if $a$ is a multiple of $n/d$. There are $d$ choices of $a$ in the range $0\le a<n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's fix an integer $a$ in ther range $1\le a<p$. By Little Fermat we know that $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$. We use this to study the number of solutions $x\in A$ such that $x\equiv a\pmod p$.

So let $x=a+kp$ for some $k$, $0\le k<p$. The binomial theorem tells us that
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{p-1}&=(a+kp)^{p-1}\\
&=a^{p-1}+\binom {p-1}1a^{p-2}kp+\sum_{i=2}^{p-1}\binom {p-1}ia^{p-1-i}k^ip^i.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here all the terms in the last sum are divisible by $p^2$, so we get that
$$
(a+kp)^{p-1}\equiv a^{p-1}+(p-1)a^{p-2}kp\pmod{p^2}.\qquad(*)
$$
Little Fermat tells us that $a^{p-1}=1+s_ap$ for some integer $s_a$. Therefore $(*)$ tells us that $(a+kp)^{p-1}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p^2$ if and only if 
$$s_a+(p-1)a^{p-2}k\equiv0\pmod p.\qquad(**)$$
Here the coefficient $(p-1)a^{p-2}$ is not divisible by $p$ so by the basic theory of linear congruences  $(**)$ is satisfied for exactly one choice of $k$ in the range $0\le k<p$.

The claim follows from this because $p\mid x\implies x^{p-1}\not\equiv1\pmod p.$

Comment: This is a standard fact covered in most textbooks, so I should not want any rep from this. Answering because my search-fu is weak today.